# Vimeo Embed Issues

Tags: html, embed, vimeo

I have embedded Vimeo in my website (Kentico) but it will not show. Instead, I am getting the following error:

[image]

Below is the code:

```
<object width=”500″ height=”281″>
  <param name=”allowfullscreen” value=”true” />
  <param name=”allowscriptaccess” value=”always” />
  <param name=”movie” value=”http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=5367093&server=vimeo.com&show_title=1&show_byline=1&show_portrait=0&color=00adef&fullscreen=1″ />
  <embed src=”http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=5367093&server=vimeo.com&show_title=1&show_byline=1&show_portrait=0&color=00adef&fullscreen=1″ type=”application/x-shockwave-flash” allowfullscreen=”true” allowscriptaccess=”always” width=”500″ height=”281″>
  </embed>
</object>
```

I am following this tutorial: http://www.miracletutorials.com/howto-embed-vimeo/

Comment: Ah. I fixed it by using Vimeo's solution: <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/VIDEO_ID" width="600" height="500" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>

Comment: No Flash Player installed?